# Is it possible to assign ToolTip text (containing non-latin characters) in a Control Template of a WPF custom control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, encoding, custom-controls, tooltip

In a WPF app I have a custom control. I would like the ToolTip for objects, derived from this custom control, depends on a value of one of the attributes of this custom control.

Is it possible to declare it in a Control Template of this custom control?

Something like:

```
<ControlTemplate>
??? // <!--XAML ToolTip declaration -->
...
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>                    
   <Trigger Property="MyProperty" Value="FirstValue">
     <Setter ...???  />  // <!--XAML ToolTip text assignment -->
   </Trigger>
   ... 
   <Trigger Property="MyProperty" Value="SecondValue">
     <Setter ...???  />  // <!--XAML ToolTip text assignment -->
   </Trigger>  
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**Edited (added):**

I have found the solution:

```
   <MultiTrigger>
     <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
       <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
       <Condition Property="MyProperty" Value="FirstValue" />
     </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
     <Setter TargetName="PART_Backgr" Property="ToolTip" Value="Available"/>
   </MultiTrigger>

   <MultiTrigger>
     <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
       <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
       <Condition Property="MyProperty" Value="SecondValue" />
     </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
     <Setter TargetName="PART_Backgr" Property="ToolTip" Value="Sold"/>
   </MultiTrigger>
```

It is working excellent.
But one problem remained: In fact `Value="Available"` and others such values should contain non-latin characters (the application is localized in Russian language). When I am trying to compile it with `Value="Свободно"`, I get en error:
**'Invalid character in the given encoding.' XML is not valid.**

What solution could be to this problem? Maybe I could change somewhere the encoding by which Generic.xaml page compiles? Or change XAML code somehow? 
(In fact, in every window I have lots of non-latin characters in XAML and everything compiles OK. But, maybe, the problem is in the way they used.)

Comment: See my updated answer, I get no error when using     <TextBlock Text="Свободно" ToolTip="Свободно"/>

Comment: Thanks Aviad! Please, see my new comment to your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this not work?

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>                    
    <Trigger Property="MyProperty" Value="FirstValue">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="..."/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTempalte.Triggers>
```

To try and address your other issue, the following works for me without any special changes:

```
<TextBlock Text="Свободно" ToolTip="Свободно"/>
```

I copied and pasted that text from your question into my XAML code.

Comment: Aviad, thank you! In fact, you put your post while I was typing mine - they are almost similar. Please, have a look at my new problem (in updated question) - maybe you could help me with it also.

Comment: And your suggestion is OK. +1

Comment: Yes, it works for me also. But only in exact way as you suggested and in xaml of general wpf window. If I try to use Property="ToolTip" Value="Свободно" in a Setter tag of a ControlTemplate xaml (Generic.xaml window), I get that mentioned error.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to use ToolTip="Свободно" rather than Property="ToolTip" Value="Свободно" approach in ControlTemplate xaml also? (I don't know how it is possible)

Comment: Works for me inside a style as well, inside a control template inside a custome control, everywhere. One thing tho, when I put it into the Generic.xaml of my custom control, visual studio warned me that it contained Unicode and asked me if I wanted to save it as Unicode, when I answered yes, everything was ok again.

Comment: Your information is encouraging. I will search where my problem is. (Unfortunately my Visual Studio asks me nothing - just tries to compile and gives an error). Thanks, I will dig into VS settings also.

Comment: Aviad, thanks to your encouraging, I managed to do it. Though, only in such a way: Property="ToolTip" Value="&#x0421;&#x0432;&#x043E;&#x0431;&#x043E;&#x0434;&#x043D;&#x043E;" So, I succeeded only using unicode hex text representation for custom control declaration. I don't know why my VS2008 behaves like this. But, nevertheless, the problem is solved! Thank you very much!

Comment: Ouch, that looks painful :) keep looking, maybe you need to set the locale of your visual studio to en-US, instead of russian maybe, for it to work correctly, there must be a better way.